# Set global variables in config with navigator.globalization

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I'm trying to set certain titles and strings in my app to a different language upon recognising the locale from a mobile phone.

I'm using a App.utils.Global class to set certain things like the code down here. This doesn't seem to work, my default name stays the same. When I print the config values after I change it it's actually loaded with the changed name. Is the view I'm outputting the name in painted before the globalization plugin is actually done changing things?

How can I prevent the rest of the app to execute things before setting the right global variables upon the device it's localeName? Or is there another way of doing this? I know there are probably better ways to do localisation in Sencha but because I only have a few strings this seemed the easiest solution.

Thanks in advance

```
Ext.define('App.utils.Global', {
    singleton: true,
    alias: 'widget.global',
    config: 
    {
        namelabel: 'default name',
    },

    constructor: function(config) {

        this.initConfig(config);
        that = this;

        if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry|IEMobile)/)) {

            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
            function onDeviceReady() {

                navigator.globalization.getLocaleName(
                    function (locale) {

                        if(locale.value == 'en_US'){
                            that.setNamelabel('ENGLISH NAME');
                        }

                        else if(locale.value == 'nl_NL'){
                            that.setNamelabel('DUTCH NAME');
                        }

                    },
                    function () {
                        alert('Error getting locale\n');
                    }
                );

            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having the "deviceready" event handler inside a class constructor, you ought to have that in your *app.js* file.

Then, inside the "deviceready" event handler, run the Ext.Application() method to start the app construction.